# How to change table cells background color based on a digit of a string of a SQLite table

Tags: php

I fetching strings from a table in a format of 12 digits like: "**000000111100**", "**001111110000**", "**111111111111**"... and I want to achieve a graphical representation of it like in this print screen for field set = Season, where digit "0" is associated to color1 and digit "1" to color2:

[image]

Using single digits associated to individual columns, I can get that graphical representation with this code:

```
<?php
$myID = $_GET['myID'];
try
{
    $conn = new PDO('sqlite:db/myDatabase.db');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myID='$myID'");
    $stmt->execute();
    $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (!empty($data))
    {
        foreach ($data as $row)  // I'm not sure if FOREACH is needed here
        {
            echo "<table><tr>";
            if ($row['jan'] == '1')
            {
                echo "<td class='season1' >Jan</td>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<td class='season2' >Jan</td>";
            }
            if ($row['feb'] == '1')
            {
                echo "<td class='season1' >Feb</td>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<td class='season2' >Feb</td>";
            }
            if ($row['mar'] == '1')
            {
                echo "<td class='season1' >Mar</td>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<td class='season2' >Mar</td>";
            }
            if ($row['apr'] == '1')
            {
                echo "<td class='season1' >Apr</td>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<td class='season2' >Apr</td>";
            }
            if ($row['mai'] == '1')
            {
                echo "<td class='season1' >May</td>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<td class='season2' >May</td>";
            }
            if ($row['jun'] == '1')
            {
                echo "<td class='season1' >Jun</td>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<td class='season2' >Jun</td>";
            }
            if ($row['jul'] == '1')
            {
                echo "<td class='season1' >Jul</td>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<td class='season2' >Jul</td>";
            }
            if ($row['aug'] == '1')
            {
                echo "<td class='season1' >Aug</td>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<td class='season2' >Aug</td>";
            }
            if ($row['sep'] == '1')
            {
                echo "<td class='season1' >Sep</td>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<td class='season2' >Sep</td>";
            }
            if ($row['oct'] == '1')
            {
                echo "<td class='season1' >Oct</td>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<td class='season2' >Oct</td>";
            }
            if ($row['nov'] == '1')
            {
                echo "<td class='season1' >Nov</td>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<td class='season2' >Nov</td>";
            }
            if ($row['dec'] == '1')
            {
                echo "<td class='season1' >Dec</td>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<td class='season2' >Dec</td>";
            }
            echo "</tr></table>";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No records found.";
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
?>
```

My question is how can I display these strings to achieve a result like in the print screen, based on that strings from my table?

I addressed this question in a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74317616/display-different-background-color-for-divs-based-on-a-result-individual-digit) but I can't make it work.

Comment: `break these strings again in basic digits, associate every (12) digits to a month, display the months and apply the background color `...there are multiple tasks here. Break it down and research and implement each one individually, as you move towards the finished solution in stages. Where are you getting stuck within that list of jobs, exactly?

Comment: _"break these strings again in basic digits"_ - no need to explicitly "break" them - you can access the individual characters (technically, bytes - but that makes no difference here, if the characters are only 0 and 1) in a string via index. If you got `$season = "000000111100";`, then you can use `$season[0]` to access that first `0` for January, etc.

Comment: @ADyson all depends how you look at it, From a distant point of view, the problem is solved but that solution involves for me to change the structure of the databse and that is very inconvenient. Trying to solve it with the actual record type is imposible for me since i'm doing this for myself and my knowledge base is far behind, so im stuck at the point that i have the records and need to write a code for it.

Comment: @CBroe, yes I fetch the strings like you mentioned **"000000111100"**, in that format where the characters are only 0 and 1, but i dont know how to handle it to get that prinscreen. The only method i managed to get that is that basic handling I already shown above.

Comment: `i have the records and need to write a code for it`...which is why I suggested breaking the problem down into the much smaller steps I listed, and figuring each one out separately. CBroe already suggested how you can do the first part. Here's a simple demo of the general idea: https://3v4l.org/d00nh . So in other words, you can use it like an array. You can access the individual parts, or loop through it, etc.

Comment: So then you can imagine something like this: https://3v4l.org/OUZtv . Or if we decide to make it a lot less repetitive, this: https://3v4l.org/uIb0d

Comment: @ADyson, both solution looks good, the first one lokks more on my knowledge, but second looks more elegant.

Comment: @ADyson, dont matter whcih one is used, but the essential is to use the strings as it is and avoid introducing more 12 columns in the database for that

Comment: Well it certainly achieves that. I wrote it up as an Answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the string of digits like an array, and access individual characters from it. You can also derive the month name from the count number, meaning you don't need an individual `if` clause for each month. Instead this loop should do what you need:

```
$monthsData = "000000111100";

for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($monthsData); $i++)
{
    $dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $i+1);
    $monthName = $dateObj->format('M');
    
    echo "<td class='season".($monthsData[$i] == 1 ? "1" : "2")."'>$monthName</td>";
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/tkOud

Comment: I think i've got your ideea just now on this https://3v4l.org/OUZtv thank you

Comment: @ADyson you have voted to close AND answered this question ...which is generally questionable behavior.  It would have been expected that you retract your close vote upon deciding to answer. Do you feel this question should be reopened? If so, please cast a reopen vote.  If you feel this question is not a good fit for SO, please cast a delete vote.

Comment: Should the question be edited to exclude the part about actually styling elements? This answer is merely demonstrating how conditionally write a classname (and how to translate an integer into an abbreviation month name). I feel pretty confident that SO has dupe targets for these kinds of basic tasks.

Comment: @mickmackusa I voted to close intially, then changed my mind as I felt I understood it, answered, forgot to retract the close vote, and then voted to re-open, but that suggestion was rejected by others.